# Rust - cannot borrow as mutable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm getting an error trying to run this code:

```rust
use serde_json::{json, Map, Value};

fn get_json() -> Map<String, Value>{
    let r = json!({
        "x": "y"
    });
    let r = r.as_object().unwrap();
    return r.clone();
}
fn main() {
    let mut a = get_json();
    
    let mut d: Map<String, Value> = Map::new();
    let x = a["x"].as_str().unwrap();
    a.insert("g".to_string(), Value::String("x".to_string()));
    d.insert(x.to_string(), Value::Object(a));
}
```

Error:

```
cannot borrow `a` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
mutable borrow occurs hererustcE0502
main.rs(14, 13): immutable borrow occurs here
main.rs(16, 14): immutable borrow later used here
```

I'm not even trying to borrow a, I'm only trying to insert something to it.

Comment: `a["x"].as_str().unwrap()` gives you a `&str`: a reference to string data which is stored in the map. Rust stops you modifying `a` while you're still accessing this reference, in case this interaction invalidates the string which `x` refers to. For example, inserting a new thing into the map might mean it has to resize, meaning it has to copy its data to a bigger backing array, which means it moves the string which `x` refers to, meaning that `x` points to garbage. To fix this issue, call `x.to_string()` before modifying `a`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=73796afccdacb94b0d7635f5ab4ee312

Comment: An even simpler case of invalidation is that `insert` can replace an existing value, which would drop the previous one, and thus lead to a dangling reference.

Comment: _"I'm not even trying to borrow `a`"_ → But you are: `a.insert(…)` is syntactic sugar for `Map::insert (&mut a, …)` which clearly borrows `a`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
use serde_json::{json, Map, Value};

fn get_json() -> Map<String, Value> {
    let r = json!({
        "x": "y"
    });
    r.as_object().unwrap().clone()
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = get_json();
    a.insert("g".to_string(), Value::String("x".to_string()));
    let d = Map::<String, Value>::from_iter(vec![(a["x"].to_string(), Value::Object(a))]);
}
```